# Creating a Simple Element Scroll Animation (javascript/css)

Tags: javascript, html, css, transform, translate

**Scenario/Question:**

I am creating a javascript scroll animation on my page. When the user scrolls down, the text should become visible as it translates from the side of the page in either direction and does not move past the centered position (0,0) within its container.

**Stipulations/Dependencies:**

Given the maximum scroll height, and the user's viewport height. When the scroll height is 0, the element should be originally positioned to either the far left or far right side of the screen. As the user scrolls down, the element translates back to its centered position at (0,0). This animation stops at the maximum scroll height where the page ends. The Y transformation value does not change throughout this cycle and the element's container is static.

**Here's an example:**

[image]

**These are the start and end transformations of the example**:

**Initial State:** scroll height of 0 = {transform: "translate(50vw,0)"}

*user then scrolls downward*

**Last State:** scroll height of 1391px = {transform: "translate(0,0)"}

I'm interested in making this animation dynamic so the screen size won't prohibit the translation. I am only looking for the math equation to use in place of my `transform: translate(${MATH},y)` css.

Comment: You can find similar post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64635111/animate-a-div-when-we-scroll-to-a-specific-position/64636759#64636759

Comment: @54ka The question I had described is an abstracted example. I am still interested in a solution to my specific example since the one you linked has a very specific scenario. Thanks! I will definitely look at this.

Comment: Well I found the solution i was looking for, simply just subtract the scrollMaxY from the scroll position. But I need to now make this more smooth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution with lerp. This works great, for my scenario. Using react-spring, interpolation, animate, and Spring, you can create this easily. The element starts at the far end of either side of the screen, and when you scroll, the element slowly moves inwards and stops at (0,0). I added the page width back to the interpolation function so it doesn't start it out at 0.

```js
<Spring
  native
  from={{
    x:
      document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight,
  }}
  to={{
    x: props.position.y,
  }}
>
  {({ x }) => (
    <animated.p
      style={{
        transform: x.interpolate(
          (x) =>
            `translate(${
              x +
              document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
              document.documentElement.clientHeight
            }px,0)`
        ),
      }}
    >
      ELEMENT
    </animated.p>
  )}
</Spring>;
```

Heres the docs: https://www.react-spring.io/docs/props/performance